# Java-Move nextLine with method

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedreader

I have a multi-line text file and I need to assign each line to a different array.
I have created a method for this purpose but it is not working. This is what my main method looks like.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] arr = new String[20];
    fromTextToArray(arr); //after this method call, the console needs to move next Line
    String[] arr2 = new String[20];
    fromTextToArray(arr2);
  }
```

This is what my method looks like.

```
 public static void fromTextToArray(String[] strArray) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader brTest = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("csalg.txt"));
    String text = brTest.readLine();
    brTest.readLine();
    strArray = text.split(",");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
    text = brTest.readLine(); // this is where I try to move next line for my second array
}
```

Numbers from the File:

```
1    5 4 4 7 5 5 5 5 3 3 7 7 4 5 2
2    4 5 4 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 5
4    9 10 13 9 8 12 20 16 12 16 6 9 5 5 19 15 16 16 10
8    3 5 1 3 2 7 2 4 7 6 1
```

Desired Output:

arr[] = {1,5,4,7,5,5,5,3,3,7,4,5,2}
arr2[] = {2,4,5,4,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,5}

**Is it possible to move to next line in a method? Or any different way to do so?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the reader inside the method so every time it will start from the beginning of the file. 
Also, use the try-with-resource to handle closing the reader or write a try-catch-finaly and close it yourself.

You can leave the method decide the length of the string array no need for you to do it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try (BufferedReader brTest = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("s.txt"))) {
        String[] arr = fromTextToArray(brTest.readLine());// line 1
        brTest.readLine(); // skip line 2
        String[] arr2 = fromTextToArray(brTest.readLine());// line 3
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
    }
}

public static String[] fromTextToArray(String text) throws IOException {

    String[] arr = text.split(",");
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but this just gets the line and sets to its array. For example, arr2[0] print whole line instead of first value.

Comment: it is splitting the values with comma char, can you please add an example of input and desired output? i may be able to help after that.

Comment: I just fixed it and it helped a lot! Thank you!